# how to explain the linux comm command's wrong result

Tags: linux, comm

So i am trying to compare two files(one with line number:30000 and other 10000), but the comm's result surprised me

first input content is:

```
79044630
79562151
80746665
81776377
100079031
100109122
100109586
100168781
100197424
100203652
```

second input content is:

```
79044619
79562151
80746665
81776367
100079031
100109122
100109586
100168781
100197424
100203652
100318504
100322466
100345449
100365010
100422997
41325291528
41374900954
41680701471
41777751048
41783905750
```

Output from running `comm first second`:

```
    79044619
79044630
        79562151
        80746665
    81776367
    100079031
    100109122
    100109586
    100168781
    100197424
    100203652
    100318504
    100322466
    100345449
    100365010
    100422997
    41325291528
    41374900954
    41680701471
    41777751048
    41783905750
81776377
100079031
100109122
100109586
100168781
100197424
100203652
```

Tips: I sort the input data using `sort -n` command before using `comm` command!

the comm command's wrong result is about the datas:

```
100079031
100109122
100109586
100168781
100197424
100203652
```

these data should be print on the third column, because they exist in both files!!!

is something wrong about my data?Or am I missing something?

thank u first

Comment: FYI, "snippets" are only for code that can be run in-browser (ie. JavaScript). Use the `{}` button in the editor for other block formatting.

Answer (score 2):

`comm` expects input to be sorted according to the current locale's character collation order, *not* according to numeric value.

The `-n` flag is thus the Wrong Thing here.

To sort your data according to the current locale *while* it's being passed to `comm`, you can use process substitution (and note that there are no `-n` flags below):

```
comm <(sort <first) <(sort <second)
```

And output is correctly:

```
                100079031
                100109122
                100109586
                100168781
                100197424
                100203652
        100318504
        100322466
        100345449
        100365010
        100422997
        41325291528
        41374900954
        41680701471
        41777751048
        41783905750
        79044619
79044630
                79562151
                80746665
        81776367
81776377
```

Comment: Thank u very much

Comment: how stupid i am to paint the lily, thank u very much again